# How to set env variables across the app with create-react-app on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

Hey I have my simple Todo app with the client where I have `create-react-app` installed and the server  with `node`. I want to set `env` variables across my app but I am confused how to do it properly.

I have set my `.env` file in the root directory of the app.

[image: Directory of my app]

In the `.env` file there is only `REACT_APP_HOST=http://localhost:3000`.

I wanted to display it in the `client` directory like so:

```
const { REACT_APP_HOST } = process.env;
console.log({ REACT_APP_HOST });
```

The code above shows me `undefined`. The whole `process.env` is an empty object.

I have tried to move the `.env` to the `client` directory and it works well then but thats not the point I think.

How to do it properly if I would like to use the `.env` variables also in the `server` side ? Do I need to create two separate `.env` files to serve the client and the server in my case or maybe `create-react-app` need some extra configuration to be served by one `.env` file ?

If it'll help here you have my [github repo](https://github.com/kendyl93/mern-todo-app).

Comment: Yes you would need to create an .env for your server, and for the client side which you already have set up.

Comment: my example mern app https://github.com/EliHood/ReactExpressPhotoShareApp, that uses both .env files for server and client folder. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to create two .env file . One is in client and another is in server(if needed).
2. You dont need to set any other configuration for client. By default client directory support .env if it is done with create-react-app. You may get more information at @[custom .env](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)
3. If you need to use .env for server . create .env at server folder. Add dotenv module. You have to follow instruction from this link. [dotenv doc](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: Thanks for clear solution. It works, but is there any way to share one `.env` file between client and server ? If it is possible, which one is more common practice ? To have it in one file or to devide it ?

Answer (score 5):

- Create a `.env` file in the root of your application (same level as `src`):

  ```
  REACT_APP_API = http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
  ```

That's it, by naming your variables with `REACT_APP` prefix you don't even need to use `dotenv.require()`. Now `REACT_APP_API` is available at `process.env.REACT_APP_API`

Comment: Hmm... I dont understand why you call `client` directory as a root of my app and not the `mern-todo-app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right, You must have to create a `.env` file in the root of our project. Perhaps it will be the same level as `src`.

Please note this link. https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5